# JFrames method setVisible(true) or setVisible(false) not working in a loop. Frames are not displayed properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe

JFrames not displaying properly in loop.
Code:-

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class SwingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
        final JFrame jfrm= new JFrame("A Simple Swing Application");

        final JFrame jfrm2= new JFrame("A Simple Swing Application 2");
        jfrm.setSize(275,100);

        jfrm.setLocation(100,100);
        jfrm2.setLocation(50,50);    
        jfrm2.setSize(275,100);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

        jfrm2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);           
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel("Swing means powerful GUIs.");         
        jfrm.add(jlab);    
        JButton button0= new JButton("loop");
        jfrm.add(button0);          
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        JLabel jlab2 = new JLabel("Swing means powerful GUIs again");           
        jfrm2.add(jlab2);    
        //jfrm2.setVisible(true);               

        jfrm.setVisible(true);

        button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            private boolean confirmAction;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                confirmAction = true;
                if (confirmAction) {
                    try {
                while(true)
                {
                    jfrm.setVisible(false);
                                jfrm2.setVisible(true);    

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(15000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                        System.out.println("nothing");
                    }
                            jfrm2.setVisible(false);
                    jfrm.setVisible(true);
                    }   
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

});

}

}
```

Comment: "frames are not displayed properly" what does this tell? Half drawn? None-drawn? Drawn with different colors? Drawn in background/foreground?

Comment: Thread.sleep() calls on the EDT (e.g. in a Listener) are dead wrong. You basically STOP the windowing system and then complain it doesn't work. Re-read the Swing tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that they are not updating correctly (this is my only thought since you didn't explain the issue), you should try to include these methods in the loop:

```
validate();
repaint();
```

If your issue is different, please inform us.

Answer (score 1):

The method
    
    `@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    }`
    
is executed in the EDT. Once you have implemented an infinite loop inside EDT it will stop processing any farther events and your GUI will stop responding.

A possible solution may be to start a timer and on every timer tick post relevant events to EDT, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait()`:

Replace the contents of `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` with the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(15000, new ActionListener() {
    boolean flip = false;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jfrm.setVisible(flip);
                jfrm2.setVisible(!flip);
                flip =! flip;
            }
        });
     }
});
timer.start();
```

Comment: +1  and locked by Thread.sleep(15000); , please add description to use Swing Timer instead of  infinite loop locked by Thread.sleep(15000);